# How to add row and column value as a tag of UIButton so that i can get row and column value on button click?

Tags: objective-c, tags, uibutton, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet view I added a `UIButton` in each cell of spreadsheet I want to get the `row` and `column` value on click action of that button .

Comment: Using a table or collection view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle this, Usually I create a subclass of UIButton and set property of NSInteger row and NSInteger column.

```
@interface TableButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger row;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger column;
@end
```